# HTML Container not expanding to inner-content height absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

So,

```
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="main-content>
    <div id="main-content-inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

main-content has a relative positioning, page-wrap has default positioning, main-content-inner has absolute positioning.

The problem is page-wrap height is not expanding to the height of main-content-inner.  main-content-inner displays just fine, but it is displaying outside the bounds of page-wrap. So if i set overflow to hidden on page wrap my main-content-inner gets cut off.  How do I make it so my page-wrap height expands to the tallest height of its children containers?

```
#page-wrap {
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
height:100%;
margin-bottom:-20px;
overflow:hidden;

}

#main-content {
width: 100%;

margin-left: -295px;
position:relative;

}
#main-content-inner {
left: 560px;
border-radius:8px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;
border-color:#53D8FF;
padding:20px;
padding-bottom:0;
background-color:#000000;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
min-width:60%;
max-width:60%;


}
```

Comment: give your page-wrap a position: relative;  when you use positional elements (which I don't recommend for this type of headache) then they are like floats without a clear option so you have to contain them in a positional element.

Comment: even with relative positioning on the page-wrap the child content doesn't force the page-wrap to expand.

Comment: Is 'main-content-inner' floated or something odd? Please provide CSS for both of the inner divisions as well.

Comment: added the css.  Its not floated, just absolute.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what this is supposed to look like.  Could you post a quick image of how this is roughly supposed to be laid out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `min-height` property, then why are you using the `height` property right after it.  When you set `height: 100%`, I believe you're restricting `#page-wrap` height to exactly 100%.  Try deleting the `height` definitions and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: even with only min-height set to 100% the container refuses to expand!

Comment: You might want to post more code then.  Maybe stick an example on jsFiddle.  I can't really see what the problem is without more to go off of.

Comment: Hmm, there is so much code, ill post a condensed version....but why is it that if i manually set the height of page-wrap, it works fine, but it just wont expand automatically to its child container's heights?

Comment: Well my guess is something's interfering with the height of the child elements.  CBRRacer may be right if you have floats or something like that, in which case you'd have to have to `clear: both` after then for the height to get set correctly.  When you set the height on `#page-wrap`, then the height of the container no longer depends on the child elements.  But I can't really know for sure without seeing more.